# region seems to be ignored when using Matcher.appendReplacement()

Tags: java

I'm using jdk1.7.0_79 trying to replace some text with `Matcher`.
I make extensive use of `Matcher.appendReplacement()` and `Matcher.appendTail()`, and all is fine when I set no region.

If I use `Matcher.region(startPosition, endPosition)` before the `Matcher.find()` loop, the first `Matcher.appendReplacement()` method appends all input from the start of the input text to the matched element, while I'd expect it to start at the region start position.

I looked at the Matcher sources and the implementation seems to confirm this behavior: `lastAppendPosition` is reset to 0 in `Matcher.region()` and used as a starting point in `Matcher.appendReplacement()`. The same goes for `Matcher.appendTail()`.

Can somebody confirm that this is the intended behavior? Am I supposed to handle things myself when using regions? Why so, as it would be trivial to set `lastAppendPosition` to the region start position in `Matcher.region()`?

I don't show my code because it is quite convoluted. I might prepare a simple test case if needed.

Edit: test added

```
package test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestMatcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eu blandit sapien.";
        int regionStartPos = 6;
        int regionEndPos = inputText.length()-7;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("elit");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputText);
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        matcher.region(regionStartPos, regionEndPos);
        System.out.println("Region start = " + matcher.regionStart());
        System.out.println("Region end = " + matcher.regionEnd());
        System.out.println("Skipped beginning = " + inputText.substring(0, regionStartPos));
        System.out.println("Skipped ending = " + inputText.substring(regionEndPos, inputText.length()));
        matcher.find();
        matcher.appendReplacement(result, "ELIT");
        matcher.appendTail(result);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

The above code gives the following result. As you can see, the final output contains the parts outside the region:

```
Region start = 6
Region end = 77
Skipped beginning = Lorem 
Skipped ending = sapien.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing ELIT. Maecenas eu blandit sapien.
```

Comment: "I might prepare a simple test case if needed" - I would recommend that.

Comment: Test added as suggested

Comment: The only explicit item I could find in the documentation reads: "The implicit state of a matcher includes the input character sequence as well as the *append position*, which is initially zero and is updated
by the `appendReplacement` method." Also the source implementation does confirm your question, i.e. the cursor in `appendReplacement` is initialized as `0` within the method's body. On top of that `Matcher` is final, so no anonymous joy here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you figured out, `Matcher.region(int start, int end)` is resetting the `Matcher.lastAppendedPosition` to 0.

You asked if this is the "intended behavior".
This behavior is not documented in the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), so I would argue that it is **not** intended behavior (i.e., it is a bug) based on the following reasoning:

The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) specifically states that the only methods that will affect the "append position" are:

1. `Matcher.appendReplacement(StringBuffer sb, String replacement)`
2. `Matcher.appendTail(StringBuffer sb)`
3. `Matcher.reset()`
4. `Matcher.reset(CharSequence input)`

The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) also states that the `Matcher.usePattern(Pattern newPattern)` will not affect the "append position".

It therefore seems inconsistent that `Matcher.region(int start, int end)` would reset the "append position" without mentioning it in the JavaDoc.

---

As a work-around, I used a modified version of the `fixRegion()` method shared by @xtian above.

```
private static void setRegionAndMaintainAppendPosition(Matcher m, int start, int end) throws Exception
{
  java.lang.reflect.Field lastAppendPositionField = Matcher.class.getDeclaredField("lastAppendPosition");
  lastAppendPositionField.setAccessible(true);
  int lastAppendPosition = (int) lastAppendPositionField.get(m);
  m.region(start, end);
  lastAppendPositionField.set(m,lastAppendPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be usecases where appendReplacement and appendTail are useful as implemented, i.e. ignoring regions, but in my case they are not. If the implementation could allow me to choose its behavior by a simple flag somewhere, I'd be very pleased.
Lacking that, here is what I came up with as a workaround for people needing regions to be respected.

1. just after defining the region, call fixRegion(), which will update the lastAppendPosition if needed;
2. instead of calling the Matcher.appendTail(), use the new appendTail() method

What follows is the updated test

```
package test;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestMatcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String inputText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eu blandit sapien.";
        int regionStartPos = 6;
        int regionEndPos = inputText.length()-7;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("elit");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputText);
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        matcher.region(regionStartPos, regionEndPos);
        fixRegion(matcher); // ADDED
        System.out.println("Region start = " + matcher.regionStart());
        System.out.println("Region end = " + matcher.regionEnd());
        System.out.println("Skipped beginning = " + inputText.substring(0, regionStartPos));
        System.out.println("Skipped ending = " + inputText.substring(regionEndPos, inputText.length()));
        matcher.find();
        matcher.appendReplacement(result, "ELIT");
//      matcher.appendTail(result);
        appendTail(matcher, inputText, result); // ADDED
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static void fixRegion(Matcher m) throws Exception {
        Field lastAppendPositionField = Matcher.class.getDeclaredField("lastAppendPosition");
        lastAppendPositionField.setAccessible(true);
        int lastAppendPosition = (int) lastAppendPositionField.get(m);
        if (lastAppendPosition==0) {
            lastAppendPositionField.set(m, m.regionStart());
        }
    }

    private static void appendTail(Matcher m, String input, StringBuffer result) throws Exception {
        Field lastAppendPositionField = Matcher.class.getDeclaredField("lastAppendPosition");
        lastAppendPositionField.setAccessible(true);
        int lastAppendPosition = (int) lastAppendPositionField.get(m);
        if (lastAppendPosition<m.regionStart()) {
            lastAppendPosition = m.regionStart();
        }
        result.append(input.substring(lastAppendPosition, m.regionEnd()));
    }


}
```

Output:

```
Region start = 6
Region end = 77
Skipped beginning = Lorem 
Skipped ending = sapien.
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing ELIT. Maecenas eu blandit
```

Comment: For simple cases like this test, ankhzet suggestion is of course preferable. But if you have a large input with many regions, this solution might be worth it I guess (could be optimized by getting the Field once).

Comment: my answer just states: you ask `Matcher.region()` to do something, what it doesn't supposed to do. If you require that specific behavior - than you should `extend` `Matcher` class (via encapsulation, for example). It's something, code-reusability exists for.

Comment: My opinion is that Matcher has been implemented in a counter-intuitive way. The easy way to extend Matcher has been prevented by making it final: another questionable design decision. If they only made lastAppendPosition public... But I guess it's just me.

Comment: Honestly, I can see no counter-intuitivity there. Method has it's description in `javadoc` and is called `.region()`. Not `.trimRegion()`, nor `.usableRegion()`, so I couldn't understand, why You thinking it should affect replacing/appending-related functionality. P.S. Possible reasons why Matcher and Pattern had made final you can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403589/why-are-there-no-public-constructors-in-pattern-and-matcher-classes-of-java).

Comment: It is not a matter of using region() for replacing. The appendReplacement() method is said to implement "a non-terminal append-and-replace step" but the doc doesn't say you should not use it together with region(), although the method fails (by appending from the start) if you change the region more than once WHEN SEARCHING. Am I wrong about it?

Comment: An example: call region(), find() something, call appendReplacement(), call region(), find() something, call appendReplacement() --> WRONG OUTPUT

Comment: I know that the doc for region() says "Invoking this method resets the matcher", so you will say that all works as documented (but not as expected, by me at least), but then how do I implement my usecase without a lot of complicated logic?

Comment: As you said, `Invoking this method resets the matcher`. Thats all. Yours expectation for method's behavior based on the wrong understanding of it's purpose. And, "a lot of complicated logic"? Where?

Comment: I posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233241/using-matcher-appendreplacement-with-multiple-regions

Answer (score 0):

> The region is the part of the input sequence that will be searched to find a match.

`searched to find a match`. Nothing about trimming of input in results.

**Upd.**

If you think that provided test case should produce `ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing ELIT. Maecenas eu blandit`, then why not just

```
int regionStartPos = 6;
int regionEndPos = inputText.length()-7;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("elit");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputText.substr(regionStartPos, regionEndPos - regionStartPos));
```

?