# Using Matcher.appendReplacement() with multiple regions

Tags: java

The java Matcher.appendReplacement() method (with appendTail()) is supposed to let me transform a source text into a result text while replacing all occurrences of a pattern.
The algorithm in pseudolanguage would be something like:

```
while Matcher.find() {
  call Matcher.appendReplacement()
}
call Matcher.appendTail()
```

If the pattern is searched only inside a given region, all is fine:

```
call Matcher.region()
while Matcher.find() {
  call Matcher.appendReplacement()
}
call Matcher.appendTail()
```

The problem arises when, after matching inside a region, I want to move the region further:

```
call Matcher.region()
while Matcher.find() {
  call Matcher.appendReplacement()
}
call Matcher.region()
while Matcher.find() {
  call Matcher.appendReplacement()
}
call Matcher.appendTail()
```

This doesn't work because region() resets the matcher so that Matcher.appendReplacement() restarts from the beginning of the text, causing the result to contain duplication of some part of the source.

This happens by design, as the javadoc says.

What is the correct way of replacing a pattern that can be located inside more than one region?

*Edit: java example added, text example removed*

The following java example shows that from an input like

dog1 start dog2a dog2b end dog3 start dog4a dog4b end dog5

you don't get the expected output

dog1 start cat2a cat2b end dog3 start cat4a cat4b end dog5

```
package test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestMatcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String inputText = "dog1 start dog2a dog2b end dog3 start dog4a dog4b end dog5";
        System.out.println("input  = " + inputText);
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("dog");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputText);

        int startPos = inputText.indexOf("start");
        int endPos = inputText.indexOf("end");
        System.out.println("Setting region to " + startPos + "," + endPos);
        matcher.region(startPos, endPos);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            matcher.appendReplacement(result, "cat");
        }
        System.out.println("Partial result = " + result);

        startPos = inputText.indexOf("start", endPos);
        endPos = inputText.indexOf("end", startPos);
        System.out.println("Setting region to " + startPos + "," + endPos);
        matcher.region(startPos, endPos);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            matcher.appendReplacement(result, "cat");
        }
        matcher.appendTail(result);
        System.out.println("Final result   = " + result);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
input  = dog1 start dog2a dog2b end dog3 start dog4a dog4b end dog5
Setting region to 5,23
Partial result = dog1 start cat2a cat
Setting region to 32,50
Final result   = dog1 start cat2a catdog1 start dog2a dog2b end dog3 start cat4a cat4b end dog5
```

Comment: Whats wrong with `Pattern.compile("start.*?(dog).*?end").matcher()`, for example?

Comment: My text example wasn't good enough. As shown in the pseudocode, the find() method is called repeatedly to replace all occurrences of the pattern in each region. I think your suggestion wouldn't work. Fixing the text example now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't sub-regions must be handled by separate matcher? Like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String inputText = "dog1 start dog2a dog2b end dog3 start dog4a dog4b end dog5";

  System.out.println("Input          = " + inputText);
  StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(start(.*?)end)");

  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputText);

  while (matcher.find()) {
    int s = matcher.start();
    int e = matcher.end();
    System.out.printf("(%d .. %d) -> \"%s\"\n", s, e, matcher.group(1));
    matcher.appendReplacement(result, processSubGroup(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2)));
  }
  matcher.appendTail(result);
  System.out.println("Final result   = " + result);
}

static String processSubGroup(String subGroup, String contents) {
  StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("dog");

  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(subGroup);

  while (matcher.find())
    matcher.appendReplacement(result, "cat");

  matcher.appendTail(result);
  return result.toString();
}
```

Or, without log-related stuff and more simpler:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String inputText = "dog1 start dog2a dog2b end dog3 start dog4a dog4b end dog5";

  StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(start(.*?)end)");

  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputText);

  while (matcher.find())
    matcher.appendReplacement(result, processSubGroup(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2)));

  matcher.appendTail(result);
  System.out.println("Final result   = " + result);
}

static String processSubGroup(String subGroup, String contents) {
  return Pattern.compile("dog").matcher(subGroup).replaceAll("cat");
}
```

Result:

```
Input          = dog1 start dog2a dog2b end dog3 start dog4a dog4b end dog5
(5 .. 26) -> "start dog2a dog2b end"
(32 .. 53) -> "start dog4a dog4b end"
Final result   = dog1 start cat2a cat2b end dog3 start cat4a cat4b end dog5
```

Or more abstract approach:

```
interface GroupProcessor {
  String process(String group);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String inputText = "dog1 dogs dog2a dog2b enddogs cow1 dog3 cows cow2a cow2b endcows dog4 dogs dog5a dog5b enddogs cow3";

  String result = inputText;

  result = processGroup(result, "dogs*enddogs", (group) -> {
    return Pattern.compile("dog").matcher(group).replaceAll("cat");
  });

  result = processGroup(result, "cows*endcows", (group) -> {
    return Pattern.compile("cow").matcher(group).replaceAll("sheep");
  });

  System.out.println("Input        = " + inputText);
  System.out.println("Final result = " + result);
}

static String processGroup(String input, String regex, GroupProcessor processor) {
  StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(String.format("(%s)", regex.replace("*", "(.*?)")));

  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

  while (matcher.find())
    matcher.appendReplacement(result, processor.process(matcher.group(1)));

  matcher.appendTail(result);
  return result.toString();
}
```

Which will give us:

```
Input        = dog1 dogs dog2a dog2b enddogs cow1 dog3 cows cow2a cow2b endcows dog4 dogs dog5a dog5b enddogs cow3
Final result = dog1 cats cat2a cat2b endcats cow1 dog3 sheeps sheep2a sheep2b endsheeps dog4 cats cat5a cat5b endcats cow3
```

---

**Upd.**

The reasons, why `Matcher.region()` resets implicit matcher state and, thus, `lastAppendPosition`.

`appendReplacement` and `appendTail` is somewhat a move-only-forward mechanism, while `.region()` is not so deterministic.

Assume following situation: for string of 100 chars you applied region 0..20, performed `find()`-`appendReplacement()` loop, then moved region to, f.e., 30..60, and performed replacement loop again.

Now you have 0..100 source string and, f.e., 0..60 replacement result string in `StringBuffer`.

Next, you applying region 10..40 to source string... and what next? If that region of source string doesn't contains matches - OK, doing nothing, but if it *does* contain matches? Where should `appendReplacement` append/insert results of replacement? The result string is already past that 10..40 region and `appendReplacement` only *appends*, not *replaces* partitions of string in output buffer.

If there existed some constraint mechanism, that limited region setup only to something like `MAX(start, lastAppendPosition)..MIN(end, sourceLength)`, then ok, append mechanism would work fine, but `.region()` method has no such limitations, or they (that limitations) would make `.region()` method quite useless for searching (which *is* the main purpose of `.region()` method).

Thats why `.region()` resets implicit state of matcher, making it not so useful in conjunction with `appendReplacement()`-related stuff. If you require different behavior - extend `Matcher` class via encapsulation.

Comment: So the proper way of using multiple regions is not to use region() at all. It would be much simpler if only region() didn't reset the append position (I fail to see why it does so).

Comment: If I understand you right, you're saying that region() has been made "useless" on purpose (from the point of using it with appendReplacement), to prevent people from using it backwards. Which is a very unlikely and illogical usecase in my opinion. I would rather find a problem when using it backwards (which wouldn't happen because, as you say, appendReplacement is conceptually a move-only-forward mechanism) rather than have a problem when using it forward. Or maybe the appendReplacements should honor the region and there would be no misunderstandings.

Comment: Oh, God... `.region()` wasn't made "useless" on any purpose, it was made "useful" on purpose of `searching`. Because `.find()` method relays on matchers inner state, using regions in conjunction with it is only useful if `.region()` will reset implicit matcher's state. `appendReplacements` can't honor the region because region appliance serves only for `.find()`-related stuff. `.region()` wasn't made for `append- Replacement()/Tail()`-ing, only for searching. If you require `region` analog for append/replacing - implement it by yourself. It's not so hard.

Comment: ankhzet, I'm very grateful that you're spending so much time answering my questions, but it's sad to see you getting arrogant and treating me like a dumb idiot just because our opinions differ. In my last comment I didn't question the existence of region() and I didn't say that it should not reset the matcher: just the append position (which, as you know, is not used for searching). In any case, I really appreciate your solution and will use it next time.

Comment: @xtian, Eh, sorry if that my exclamation gives you wrong impression, but i'm not thinking nothing about "dumb idiot" or such, i'm just wondering, why you so confident, that `.region()` (search-helper function) must honor append/replace mechanics of `Matcher`? Eh, i just don't understand... Yeah, it _might_ be useful in some usecases, but that will make anything a little bit overcomplicated...  Anyway, sorry for whatever was looking like arrogance =(